Dataframe sorting of data containing mixed alphanumeric characters
Issue:
Trying to sort the below dataframe for excel data(note this is a small sample set of multiple rows with information that can range from A#-Z# followed by AA# etc.,(like how the excel sheet would be done)(#- ranges from 0 to 100):
Input
"Pin No": ['J11', 'J1', 'A2', 'A11', 'A1', 'AA2', 'AB2'],
        "Pin Name": ['pin1', 'pin2', 'pin3', 'pin4', 'pin5', 'pin6', 'pin7']

Output requirements:
Pin No Pin Name
  A1     pin5
  A2     pin3
 A11     pin4
  J1     pin2
 J11     pin1
 AA2     pin6
 AB2     pin7

Code attempted:
import pandas as pd
import re

# Initial DataFrame
def main():
    df = pd.DataFrame({
        "Pin No": ['J11', 'J1', 'A2', 'A11', 'A1', 'AA2', 'AB2'],
        "Pin Name": ['pin1', 'pin2', 'pin3', 'pin4', 'pin5', 'pin6', 'pin7']
    })
    # Apply the split_pin function to the 'Pin No' column
    df['Pin No Split'] = df['Pin No'].apply(split_pin)
        
    # Sort based on alphabetic part first, then numeric part
    df_sorted = df.sort_values(by=['Pin No Split'], key=lambda x: x.apply(lambda y: (y[0], y[1]))).drop(columns=['Pin No Split']).reset_index(drop=True)
    
    # Display the sorted DataFrame
    print(df_sorted)
    # Function to split Pin No into alphabetic and numeric components
def split_pin(pin):
    # Regex to split Pin No into alphabetic and numeric parts
    match = re.match(r"([A-Za-z]+)(\d+)", pin)
    print(match)
    if match:
        alphabetic_part = match.group(1)
        print(alphabetic_part)
        numeric_part = int(match.group(2))  # Convert numeric part to integer for sorting
        print(numeric_part)
        return (alphabetic_part, numeric_part)
    else:
        return (pin, 0)

But I am unable to get the sorting correctly. I get the below output, not sure which part of my approach is wrong:
Pin No Pin Name
0     A1     pin5
1     A2     pin3
2    A11     pin4
3    AA2     pin6
4    AB2     pin7
5     J1     pin2
6    J11     pin


You could split the letters/digits with str.extract and sort with numpy.lexsort:
import numpy as np

tmp = df['Pin No'].str.extract(r'(\D+)(\d+)')

# sort by number, letter, letters length
# highest priority is last
out = df.iloc[np.lexsort([tmp[1].astype(int), tmp[0], tmp[0].str.len()])]

Another option could be to use a custom function as key, for example by padding the letters/digits to have a fixed length (e.g., 5 characters each):
id_fill = lambda x: x.str.replace(r'(\D+)(\d+)',
                                  lambda m: m.group(1).rjust(5)
                                           +m.group(2).zfill(5),
                                  regex=True)

out = df.sort_values(by='Pin No', key=id_fill)

Output:
  Pin No Pin Name
4     A1     pin5
2     A2     pin3
3    A11     pin4
1     J1     pin2
0    J11     pin1
5    AA2     pin6
6    AB2     pin7

Intermediates:
# lexsort approach
   number letters  letter_len  order
0      11       J           1      4
1       1       J           1      2
2       2       A           1      3
3      11       A           1      1
4       1       A           1      0
5       2      AA           2      5
6       2      AB           2      6

# custom key function approach
# with - as padding char for clarity
0    ----J00011
1    ----J00001
2    ----A00002
3    ----A00011
4    ----A00001
5    ---AA00002
6    ---AB00002
Name: Pin No, dtype: object


Thanks so much. This worked really well even for large set of data. I had not considered using numpy.lexsort, so thanks again for the pointer.

Another possible solution, although not so elegant as @mozway's lexsort solution. The steps are:

It begins by splitting each string in the Pin No column at the transition from a non-digit to a digit using the regular expression r'(?<=\D)(?=\d)' with the str.split method, which returns a dataframe with two columns.

The assign method is then used to create a new column l that stores the length of the first split component.

The numbers are converted to integers with astype to ensure correct comparisons in the sorting step.

df is subsequently sorted by the l column, followed by the first and second split components, using the sort_values method.

Finally, the iloc method selects the rows corresponding to the sorted index.


df.iloc[
    df['Pin No'].str.split(r'(?<=\D)(?=\d)', regex=True, expand=True)
    .assign(l = lambda x: x[0].str.len()).astype({1: int})
    .sort_values(['l', 0, 1]).index, :]

Output:
  Pin No Pin Name
4     A1     pin5
2     A2     pin3
3    A11     pin4
1     J1     pin2
0    J11     pin1
5    AA2     pin6
6    AB2     pin7


Thanks, @mozway, for fixing my solution!
